# NestJS does importing module to AppModule will make it available to other modules?

Tags: nestjs

I am learning NestJS I was reading the documentation but couldn't find an answer for my question.

If I have my infrastructure module:

```
@Module({
imports: [DatabaseModule],
controllers: [],
providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
        provide: 'RequestClient',
        useClass: AxiosRequestClient
    },
    {
        provide: 'FileStorage',
        useClass: S3FileStorage
    }
],
exports: ['RequestClient', 'FileStorage', DatabaseModule]
```

})
export class InfrastructureModule {}

and I import this into my AppModule

```
    @Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            load: [filesystemConfig, awsConfig, databaseConfig],
            isGlobal: true,
            cache: true
        }),
        InfrastructureModule,
        PhysicianModule,
        PatientModule,
        RemsModule
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [ApiResponseInterceptor]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

will infrastructure module exports be available to, for example, PatientModule? Or do I need to import the InfraModule to PatientModule?

Currently when I am trying to inject I get the error:

```
export default class PatientMedicalRecordFileRepository implements IPatientMedicalRecordFileRepository {
private readonly tempPath: string
private readonly s3Path: string = 'private/patients'
private readonly cloudfrontBaseUrl: string

constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    @Inject('FileStorage') private readonly fileStorage: IFileStorageService
) {


ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't r
esolve dependencies of the PatientMedicalRecordFileRepository (ConfigService, 
?). Please make sure that the argument FileStorage at index [1] is available i
n the RemsModule context.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the root level of NestJS, you have the `AppModule`. This is the module where you need to register all modules that you want to use in your app. These includes any external modules (like `HttpModule`), and your own modules (like `InfrastructureModule`).

NestJS will use this information to build an application graph, where it shall go through all modules listed in `AppModule` and try to initialise those modules.

If you need to use `InfrastructureModule` in `PatientModule`, then you will have to import it in `PatientModule`, like:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        InfrastructureModule,  
    ],
    ...
})
export class PatientModule {}
```

Now, within `PatientModule`, you can use any services from `InfrastructureModule` that are exported.

Which means, any of these:

```
exports: ['RequestClient', 'FileStorage', DatabaseModule]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to import the Module only on the AppModule level and have it available across the other modules, you can always annotate your Module with @Global() decorator. More info can be found in official NestJS [DOCS](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#global-modules)